# How to update Hive table rows

Tags: hive, presto

I have a table that looks like this:

```
 id  | Col2 | Col3 | Text
--------------------------
  1  | ...  | ...  | "abc"   
  2  | ...  | ...  | "def 
  3  | ...  | ...  | "ghi"  
  4  | ...  | ...  | "jkl"
```

And another table that looks like this:

```
 id  | Text
-------------
  1  | "qwe"
  2  | "rty"
```

And I want to end up with a table that looks like this:

```
 id  | Col2 | Col3 | Text
--------------------------
  1  | ...  | ...  | "qwe"   
  2  | ...  | ...  | "rty" 
  3  | ...  | ...  | "ghi"  
  4  | ...  | ...  | "jkl"
```

where the original values for col2 and col3 are maintained. Essentially, I want to use the values from table 2 to update the values of table 1 where ids are the same.

I tried:

```
SELECT
    A.id,
    col1, 
    col2, 
    A.text
FROM table1 AS A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        id,
        text
    FROM table2
) AS B
    ON A.product_id = B.product_id
```

But this just returned the original table. Is there a way to achieve what I want in Presto/Hive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading Text from table `A`, it should be from table `B` or `NVL(B.text, A.Text)` if you want to update value if exists in table B and leave as is if not exists (see comment in the code)

```
INSERT OVERWRITE table1 
SELECT
    A.id,
    col1, 
    col2, 
    NVL(B.text, A.Text) as Text  -- Take Text from table B, if not exists, leave as is (A.Text)
FROM table1 AS A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.product_id = B.product_id
```

You can use `coalesce(B.text, A.Text)` instead of `NVL`, as @PiotrFindeisen mentioned, it will work fine on Presto and Hive as well.

Comment: You may want to use [`coalesce`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#coalesce) for standard, portable solution.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen Yep, you are right. coalesce() instead of NVL() will work fine on Presto and Hive as well

Comment: I used coalesce and it worked perfectly! Thanks a bunch, I had no idea that function existed before :)